# Sympy factor out from a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I have a matrix like this

```
dk =Matrix([[op],[0],[-o]])
dk*2
```

I cannot factor out factor `2` using `factor(dk*2)` or `simplify(dk*2)` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure in what context you are using these expressions.
What is the greater problem that you are trying to solve?
Are you are looking to do something along the lines of:

```
>>> op,o = symbols('op o')
>>> dk =Matrix([[2*op],[o+op**2],[-op/o]])
>>> print([[cell.as_coeff_exponent(op) for cell in row] for row in dk.tolist()])
[[(2, 1)], [(o + op**2, 0)], [(-1/o, 1)]]
```

I assume this is not what you are trying to achieve, but maybe it's a start?